# Computing intersection number of two arithmetic line bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, intersection-theory, arakelov-theory

I have some questions in Arithmetic Arakelov geometry

Let $\mathcal X\to Spec(\mathcal O_K)=C$ be an arithmetric projective variety over $C$ , where $\mathcal O_K$, ring of number filed $K$ and $\mathcal L$ be an arithmetic line bundle over $\mathcal X$ and $h$ be a positive Hermitian metric on $\mathcal L$,

Then

1- How can we compute the intersection number

$$(\overline{\mathcal L}^h)^n.(n+1)(\overline{K_{\mathcal X/C}}^{Ric(h)})$$

2.What is the definition of intersection number of two arithmetic line bundles

$$\overline{\mathcal L_1}.\overline{\mathcal L_2}$$

3.If we take $\mathcal D$  be an arithmetic divisor on $\mathcal X$, then how can we introduce 
$$\overline{\mathcal L_1}.\mathcal D$$

Comment: Have you tried to read [Arakelov theory](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511623950) by Soulé, Abramovich, Burnol,  Kramer? It's not that thick, and should give you the main ideas.

Comment: yahh, I have read them, But the fact is part 1 of my question is related to Mabuchi energy functional, and, and I am woundring to see it,